# Time conversion in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have data as following

```
pubdate=10 hours ago +0000 
pudate=Yesterday +0000
```

`pubdate=1 min ago +0000`
i want to convert in this format like this

```
Wed Jan 30 10:00:00 +0000 2013
```

please someone help me

Comment: "10 hours ago +0000" - is it a pseudo-code or real piece of data you have?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`strftime`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/strftime) on date, datetime object to convert into whatever format you want

```
1.9.3p327 :006 > date = Date.today
 => Wed, 30 Jan 2013 
1.9.3p327 :007 > time = Time.now
 => 2013-01-30 17:00:30 +0530 
1.9.3p327 :008 > date.strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y")
 => "Wed Jan 30 00:00:00 +0000 2013" 
1.9.3p327 :009 > time.strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y")
 => "Wed Jan 30 17:00:30 +0530 2013"
```